# Get values from response python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am making a request to a URL using python requests and getting the following response

```
{
    "content": {
        "root": {
            "details":"http://localhost:8080/****/root",
            "content": {
                "A": {
                "details":"http://localhost:8080/***"
                },
                "B":{
                "details":"http://localhost:8080/***"
                },
                "C":{
                "details":"http://localhost:8080/****"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get the values A, B, C in a list. How can I do that? Any inputs would be of great help.

Comment: What have you tried? You have a nested dictionary, it should not be hard to extract items from it.

Answer (score 1):

Python allows dict to be nested in another dict. So it should be straight forward.

You can iterate over the dict obtained from 'root' -> 'content' keys.

```
values = []
contents = response['root']['content']
for key, value in contents.items():
     print(key, value['details'])
     values.append(value['details']
```

Method two : Iterate over dict using keys only :

```
values = []
contents = response['root']['content']
for key in contents :
    value = contents[key]
    print(key, value['details'])
    values.append(value['details'])
print(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply read them as dict and append to a list:

```
#assuming res is the response json
Vals=[]
a = res["root"]["content"]["A"]
Vals.append(a)
```

Similarly do for B and C

Answer (score 1):

Get the values and store it in a list:

```
response = {
        "content":{
            "root":{
                    "details":"http://localhost:8080/****/root",
                    "content":{
                    "A":{
                        "details":"http://localhost:8080/***"
                    },
                    "B":{
                        "details":"http://localhost:8080/***"
                    },
                    "C":{
                        "details":"http://localhost:8080/***"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

contents = response["content"]['root']['content']
contents_list = []

for content in contents.values():
    contents_list.append(content["details"])

print(contents_list)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['http://localhost:8080/***', 'http://localhost:8080/***', 'http://localhost:8080/***']
```

But if you want to get both key and value of A, B and C. Try this:

```
for content in contents.values():
    for key, value in content.items():
        contents_list.append(f"{key}: {value}")

print(contents_list)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['details: http://localhost:8080/***', 'details: http://localhost:8080/***', 'details: http://localhost:8080/***']
```

Answer (score 0):

**You should try your self first.**

1. First understand to level in nested dictionary. Note: Give input is invalid, missing `"`.
2. Use `get` method of dictionary to fetch key.
3. you should know have to iterate over dictionary by `for` loop.
4. You should know `items` method of dictionary.
5. If you want to get value of specific keys like `A and/or B and/or C ...` then please add `if` loop before appending value to output list.

Hope this will help you.

**Code**:

```
output_list = []
for item in input_data.get("content", {}).get("root", {}).get("content", {}).items():
    #output_list.append(item[1])  # Value of Key
    output_list.append(item[1]["details"]) # Value of details from Key


print("output_list:", output_list)
```

**List Comprehension**

```
output_list = [item[1]["details"]
    for item in input_data.get("content", {}).get("root", {}).get("content", {}).items()
]
```